# How to solve Assertion Error?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to do face-detection using OpenCV2 in ros.
I use cv_bridge.

Under is face-detection code.

> 

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "image_transport/image_transport.h"
#include "cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"

class MyCvPkg
{
image_transport::Subscriber img_sub_;
image_transport::ImageTransport it_;

void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr &msg) {
  ROS_INFO("Received image");
  cv::Mat in_img = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg,"bgra8")->image;
  cv::Mat face_img =in_img.clone();

//write opencv code
double scale = 4.0;
cv::Mat gray, smallImg(cv::saturate_cast<int>(face_img.rows/scale), cv::saturate_cast<int>(face_img.cols/scale), CV_8UC1);
// グレースケール画像に変換
cv::cvtColor(face_img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
// 処理時間短縮のために画像を縮小
cv::resize(gray, smallImg, smallImg.size(), 0, 0, cv::INTER_LINEAR);
cv::equalizeHist( smallImg, smallImg);

// 分類器の読み込み
std::string cascadeName = "./haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"; // Haar-like
//std::string cascadeName = "./lbpcascade_frontalface.xml"; // LBP

cv::CascadeClassifier cascade;
cascade = cv::CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
if (cascade.empty()) {
  std::cerr << "cannot load cascade file" << std::endl;
}
//if(!cascade.load(cascadeName))
//return -1;

std::vector<cv::Rect> faces;
// マルチスケール（顔）探索
// 画像，出力矩形，縮小スケール，最低矩形数，（フラグ），最小矩形
cascade.detectMultiScale(smallImg, faces,
             1.1, 2,
             CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
             ,
             cv::Size(30, 30));

// 結果の描画
std::vector<cv::Rect>::const_iterator r = faces.begin();
for(; r != faces.end(); ++r) {
cv::Point center;
int radius;
center.x = cv::saturate_cast<int>((r->x + r->width*0.5)*scale);
center.y = cv::saturate_cast<int>((r->y + r->height*0.5)*scale);
radius = cv::saturate_cast<int>((r->width + r->height)*0.25*scale);
cv::circle( face_img, center, radius, cv::Scalar(80,80,255), 3, 8, 0 );
}
cv::imshow("window", face_img);//画像を表示．
cv::waitKey(1);

//write opencv code
}
public:
  MyCvPkg(ros::NodeHandle nh = ros::NodeHandle()) : it_(nh)
  {
    img_sub_ = it_.subscribe("image", 3, &MyCvPkg::imageCallback, this);
    cv::namedWindow("Fast", 1);
  }
};

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "my_cv_pkg_node");
  MyCvPkg mcp;
  ros::spin();
}
```

> cannot load cascade file
> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!empty()) in detectMultiScale, file /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.2.0/modules   /objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp, line 1681

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
> what():  /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.2.0/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp:1681: error: (-215) !empty() in function detectMultiScale

Cascade file cannot be loaded. Please tell me how to solve above error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277416/how-to-solve-assertion-error-?/) by [sekken](https://answers.ros.org/users/32654/sekken/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you have noticed your code is failing because it cannot open the cascade file "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml". Your error handling code is not ideal, because although it reports the error it doesn't stop execution. This means that it prints out the "cannot load cascade file" message but then continues with the algorithm anyway.

If you add the line

```
exit(1);
```

after printing the message within the if statement then the error will not only be reported but OpenCV won't then crash afterwards.

Your program will look for the cascade file in its current working directory, what this is will depend on how it is being run, using **rosrun** or **roslaunch**. if you change the "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml" string to the full path of the file on your system then it should solve this problem. Also if you use **rosrun** to start your know from the same directory as the cascade file that should also work because the node's working directory will be the same as the file you're trying to load.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2017-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1